# Whole dom re-renders when the value of an input is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a react component in which I have two states inputText and students, inputText is to track the value of input while students is an array that is used to map the list of the students. Now my issue is that whenever the value of inputText is changed, the whole dom gets re-rendered which includes the student list which has nothing to do with the inputText. Now, for a small list of 10-20 students, we won't even notice it. But I have more than 1000 students which mean react is re-rendering 1000 list items on every input change. Because of this, a change in input is reflected very slowly, and also on every change dom becomes blank for 2-3 seconds and then prints the whole list after some time.

Here's the screenshot of my states:

[image: here's the screenshot of my states]

Here's the screenshot of the onChange function which has nothing to do with the students
[image]

Comment: To be honest, this is a very bad question. share a [mre] and have a look at [ask]. don't post images of code. share more code, and maybe post a condesandbox.io link as well.

Comment: Read this: https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/usememo-and-usecallback/

Comment: @Reinier68 I have the idea of both these hooks. But there is neither a heavy computational function in this component nor a callback function passed to it via props. In fact, It is the next-js page component, i.e it has no parent.

Comment: @AaqibRasool Re-read the article then. You have 2 pieces of state. Because they are in the same component and not memoized, if you change the state of 1, all of your state variables get re-rendered. Thus you need to memoize the student result, so that when you change text in yout inputfield, the students are **not** getting re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook. [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_usememo.asp) is a good example of it being used to prevent unnecessary re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check this [article](https://www.mykytaprus.com/blog/usememo-vs-usecallback-when-to-use) look at the section `React.useCallback` there you should find an answer. Also if it is the search field I recommend you use debounce for optimization. [Here](https://www.mykytaprus.com/blog/debounce-in-controlled-components) you can find how to implement this.